# Call a Jquery method in a view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call a jquery method from inside a view, I found some help on stack overflow, however for me it does not seem to work, any idea why?

```
@{ 
    var status = Model.Status;
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(
         function DisableFeature() {
             alert("here");
         }

         @if (status != 1)
         {
             //<h1>It worked!!</h1>
             DisableFeature();
         }

        );

</script>
}
```

DisabledFeature() gets underlined in red when I call it and says "the name DisabledFeature does not exist in the current context".

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
@{ 
    var status = Model.Status;
}

@if (status != 1)
{
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      function DisableFeature() {
        alert("here");
      }

      DisableFeature();
    });
  </script>
}
```

Checking for `status` before calling javascript.

Comment: I think you meant `if(status != 1){ }`

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped me.